Spring not loading properties files in subfolders
I'm upgrading an app to Spring Boot 2 and for some reason it no longer registers the property files as they were before. My project is setup into a series of modules:
  <modules>
    <module>service-api</module>
    <module>resource</module>
    <module>war</module>
    <module>integration</module>
    <module>tests</module>
    <module>docs</module>
  </modules>

Before upgrading to SB2 my property files were read without issue from the resource module, which was laid out like this:

When I run the application using this method:
@EnableAsync
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class IgipDealingApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IgipDealingApplication.class, args);
    }
}

I get the error Could not resolve placeholder 'us.comCache.serviceUrl' despite this property existing in the property file application-DEV.yml.
I'm running the application with the dev profile and this is reflected on the logs on startup with The following profiles are active: dev but it doesn't fix the issue.
I've tried moving the properties folder to the resource directory of the module that uses it and this doesn't work. However, if I create an appplication.yml in the root of that resource directory with the property it registers:

Am I missing anything?

According to spring docs
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/external-config.html :
External Application Properties

Spring Boot will automatically find and load application.properties and application.yaml files from the following locations when your application starts:

    From the classpath

        The classpath root

        The classpath /config package

    From the current directory

        The current directory

        The config/ subdirectory in the current directory

        Immediate child directories of the config/ subdirectory



Has this changed since Spring Boot 1?

Nop. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html . But sometime in new version will be fixed something, what in old version accidentally worked

I added this to the resources tag in my pom.xml in my integration module:
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/../resource/src/main/properties</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.yml</include>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/../resource/src/main/properties/common</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
          <include>**/*.yml</include>
          <include>**/*.xml</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>

And it solved my issue.
